# Calculating P-value for Spearman's rank correlation coefficient example on Wikipedia

Tags: p-value, spearman-rho, t-distribution

The Wikipedia article [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) contains an example for calculating ρ. At the end of the sections is the statement "...with a P-value = 0.6864058 (using the t distribution)." The author does not describe how the P-value was calculated from the data in the example.

How was the P-value derived for the article's specific example?

*Note: The included links to Wikipedia's P-value and T-distribution entries are too generic to provide a clear answer.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the next section in the article, "[determining significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance)", there is the equation

$t=r\sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2}}$

If you plug in their estimate of r into that equation you get a t statistic of -0.505, which you can compare to a standard t distribution via a table or a computer.  For example (EDITED- thanks to @whuber for correcting my earlier version):

```
> spearmentt <- function(r,n){r*sqrt((n-2)/(1-r^2))}
> test <- spearmentt(-0.17575757575,10)
> test
[1] -0.5049782
> 1- pt(test,8)
[1] 0.6864058
```

It's worth noting that this is a one sided test for whether r is significantly larger than zero.  Probably more appropriate test would be

```
> pt(test,8)
[1] 0.3135942
```

which is a one-sided t-test for whether r is significantly less than zero, i.e., is there evidence of a negative correlation between TV watching and IQ.

Comment: You should use n=10, not n=8, in invoking your "spearment" function.  Indeed, `r <- 1 - 6 * 194/(10*(10^2-1)); n <- 10; t <- r * sqrt((n-2)/((1-r)*(1+r))); 1 - pt(t, n-2)` returns `0.6864058` as given by Wikipedia.

Comment: But that's the wrong t-test isn't it?  They're using a one-sided t test that will return a low p value only for a high value of r.  So any negative value of r (ie negative correlation of TV watching and IQ, which may well be the question) will return a value of p >0.5.

Comment: @PeterEllis Thanks. That mostly explains how they got their P-value. Can you clarify the function "pt" you used in your code?

Comment: I think you're right, Peter.  Indeed, the two-sided value would be 2*pt(-abs(test),8).

Comment: @RussellThackston - it's the function in R that returns the cumulative probability of getting a number in a t distribution, with given degrees of freedom, as large as the first argument.  An equivalent of my one sided t-test (testing for a value of r that is significantly smaller than zero) in Excel would be '=T.DIST(-0.5049782,8,TRUE)'.

Comment: That's essentially the kind of results `cor.test()` with `method="spearman"` should provide (`pt(r / sqrt((1 - r^2)/(n-2)), df = n-2, ...)` from the source code), that is $p=.6319674$ (while I got $p=.62718834$ from Stata 12).

Answer (score 1):

In R I would suggest using the functions rcorr from the Hmisc package and the custom function flattenCorrMatrix (http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/print.php?id=78) which you can find online. rcorr calculates the correlation matrix and the flatten function will give you easy access to correlation and p values.

Something along these lines is nice for multiple variables that you want to test for correlations:

```
#extract columns you want to test
y<-x[,c(6:7,9:14,16,17,20,21)]

#calculates spearman correlations of all possible variable pairings
z<-rcorr(as.matrix(y),type=c("spearman"))

#flattens the matrix and gives you a nice table of all results
z1<-flattenCorrMatrix(zf$r, z$P)

# write your results in csv file
write.csv(z1, file = "z1results.csv")
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Spearman correlation coefficient is a Pearson correlation coefficient calculated on the ranks of observations. Hence, you can apply p-value formulae of Pearson correlation $r$ to Spearman $\rho$.

For instance, the estimator of the variance is $\sigma^2_\rho=\frac{(n-2)}{1-\rho^2}$, you can use it in usual way to calculate the t-stat $t=\rho/\sigma_\rho$, then lookup the p-value from a table or from the CDF of t-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom.